# How to separate view custom link/url from view content

Tags: drupal

I override block using these technic https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656.

```
<div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="footer-links-regions <?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
    <div class="g4_20 tgfull">
        <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
        <?php if ($block->subject): ?>
            <h3<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $block->subject ?></h3>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
    </div>

    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div class="g16_20 tgfull mhidden" <?php print $content_attributes; ?> >
        <?php print $content ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I added custom link via admin and *Custom URL* (Link display). I realized that I can see this link *inside* content (I mean that this link is added to `$content`). I would like to handle this link and *real* content separately.

Comment: How do you add the custom link in the block? Fields?

Comment: Did you add the link in Block 'body'? Anything written in block's body will be rendered using $content